# Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'IndexSet'

Tags: swift, nsindexset

```
for number in 0..<fetchResult.count{
    imgManager.requestImage(for: fetchResult.objects(at: number) as! PHAsset, targetSize: CGSize(width:200, height:200), contentMode: .aspectFill, options: requestOptions, resultHandler: {
    image, error in
        self.imageArray.append(image!)
    })
}
```

I have following error with number in fetchResult.objects(at:number)

> cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'IndexSet'

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What is the type of `fetchResult`

Comment: @NiravD let fetchResult : PHFetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .image, options: fetchOptions)

Comment: @kimpro You need to access `fetchResult.object(at: number)` or subscript with index instead of `objects(at:)`.

Comment: @NiravD you saved me! thank you!

Comment: @kimpro Welcome mate :)

Answer (score 0):

```
for number in fetchResult{
    imgManager.requestImage(for: number as! PHAsset, targetSize: CGSize(width:200, height:200), contentMode: .aspectFill, options: requestOptions, resultHandler: {
    image, error in
        self.imageArray.append(image!)
    })
}
```